# Question on Impulse-Momentum theory

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

> A 5kg stone kicked by a student undergoes a velocity change from 6m/s
>   to 10m/s in 4 seconds;
>
> ---- What is the momentum change of the stone within the time interval?
>
> ---- What impulse was impacted on the body during this time interval?

For the first question : 
$$p_2-p_1= M V_1 - MV_2 =  M(V_1-V_2)= 5\textrm{ kg}(10-6)\textrm{m s}^{-1} =  20 \textrm{ kg m s}^{-1}$$

Is that correct for the first question?

As for the second : I'm stuck. Help.

$$\textrm{impulse}=I = F\cdot t$$
$$F = (mv-mu)/t$$
$$F = m(v-u)/t$$
$$F\cdot t = m(v-u)$$
$$\Rightarrow I = 5\textrm{ kg}(10-6)\textrm{ m s}^{-1}
  = 20 \textrm{ kg m s}^{-1}$$

is that correct? Because there has been no need to use time (4 seconds)......

or : 
$$F = ma   = 5 \textrm{ kg} \frac{(10-6)\textrm{ m s}^{-1}}{4\textrm{s}}= 5\textrm{ N}$$

$$\textrm{impulse}= I = F\cdot T= 5\textrm{ N}\cdot 4 \textrm{ s} = 20\textrm{ N s},$$

still the same 20.

Thanks

Comment: please refine your question to show your previous working so we can help you understand the physics.

Comment: Refined. Retract downvote.

Comment: I would suggest to use LaTeX markup for styling your derivations. If you want, I can edit your question for a better readability.

Comment: @Brent: go ahead, that would be useful. (For just cosmetic edits like that, I usually don't bother to ask, since it's definitely an improvement.)

Comment: @Brent Go ahead.

Comment: It seems the homework tag applies even if it is not actual homework, cf. the tag description http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info

Comment: I for one would certainly like questions like these to be tagged homework. It doesn't say anything negative - it just says more.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky

Woops, I guess I didn't get to it fast enough...sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, your thinking is correct. The impulse imparted is equal to both the applied force times the time and to the change in momentum, $$I=F\Delta t=\Delta p.$$ (This is exactly Newton's second law.) The time taken by the kick is superfluous in your question.

Comment: Thanks. Have you seen the second answer gotten from deriving acceleration. . . then force . .. then multiplying the force 5N by time 4secs? Still 20. Is that also correct?

Comment: yes. It is all the same.